micropython _thread doesn't work with pin reading
Hardware platform： Espressif ESP32-C3
laguage: micropython
issus:micropython _thread  doesn't work with pin reading
issue description:
using two thread, but  why the function displaytime()(e sacn muti 7 segments LED)  runs very slow?
about 1 second for one LED.
# define a button
pin_button = Pin(6, Pin.IN)
Buttpushflag = 1
btn_value = 0

def detec_btn():
    global  btn_value
    global  gpio_value
    while True: 
        if pin_button.value() == Buttpushflag:
            time.sleep_ms(1000)
            if pin_button.value() == Buttpushflag:
                #print("button push valid")
                btn_value = 1
                gpio_value = "1"
        else:
            btn_value = 0
            #print("button push no valid")
            gpio_value = "0"

# sacn muti 7 segments LED 
def displaytime():
    while True:
        #current_time = time.localtime()
        current_time = ds.get_time()
        #print(current_time)
        time_hour = current_time[3]
        time_min = current_time[4]
        time_sed = current_time[5]
        
        sed_h, sed_l = divid_2num(time_sed)
        display1num(2, sed_l, "0")
        time.sleep(0.001)
        display1num(3, sed_h, "0")
        time.sleep(0.001)
        
        min_h, min_l = divid_2num(time_min)
        display1num(4, min_l, "1")
        time.sleep(0.001)
        display1num(5, min_h, "0")
        time.sleep(0.001)
        #display1num(6, "-", "0")
        
        hour_h, hour_l = divid_2num(time_hour)
        display1num(6, hour_l, "1")
        time.sleep(0.001)
        display1num(7, hour_h, "0")
        time.sleep(0.001)
        

_thread.start_new_thread(displaytime,())
_thread.start_new_thread(detec_btn,())


changing pin_button.value() to  "True", the  the function displaytime()(e sacn muti 7 segments LED)  works well.

displaytime is an infinite loop, so what exactly do you mean when you say it's running slow?  The slowness is probably in divid_2num or display1num, so where is the source code of those routines?  Can you simplify the code down to an [mcve]?  Also can you post code that is simpler than that where the problem doesn't happen (e.g. with no threads)?

What if you remove time.sleep_ms line or at least reduce its argument?

nothing changes after removing time.sleep_ms

hello , running slow means one loop in displaytime need much time. one loop needs about 5 seconds if threre is a "_thread.start_new_thread(detec_btn,())" thread, but no this _thread , one loop only takes very short time may be several miliseconds. please kindly help to check.
